# C# process.mainwindowtitle showing process name instead

Tags: c#, process, mainwindow

I am writing a C# application and before I exit, I need to close another console application based on its window title... this second application (staticEngineWriter) is a C program that uses SetConsoleTitle() function to set its title.

The code I have in C# to do this is below.  The problem is it is returning the process name instead of the window title of the C application.  Seems simple enough but I wonder if it has to do with how the writer application is setting its title using the SetConsoleTitle function.

```
static void stopWriter()
{

    Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("staticEngineWriter");

    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process CurrentProcess in proc)
    {
        Console.Writeline(CurrentProcess.MainWindowTitle); //debug

        if (CurrentProcess.MainWindowTitle.Contains("My Writer"))
        {
            CurrentProcess.Kill();
        }
    }

}
```